# class used differently on different occasions in css

Tags: css

why do we sometimes use syntax like

```
.oneclass .someotherclass {

}
```

and sometimes

```
.oneclass.someotherclass {

}
```

notice in the second one there is no space between oneclass and someotherclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is a descendant selector.  `a b` matches `b`s that are inside of an `a`.

Without the space, it's simply an "and".

Comment: so then what would this do? #oneotherid .oneclass.someotherclass

Answer (score 1):

Because they mean different things. First one is for elements with the second class inside elements with the first class. Second one is for elements with both classes.

Comment: so then what would this do? #oneotherid .oneclass.someotherclass

Comment: Some element with both `oneclass` and `someotherclass`, which is a descendant of `#oneotherid`. Like the span here: `<div id="oneotherid"><p><span class="oneclass oneotherclass">This span will be selected</span></p></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The first targets `.someotherclass` under `.oneclass` while the second targets one element with both.  The first would target for example `<div class='oneclass'><div class='someotherclass'></div></div>` while the second would target `<div class='oneclass someotherclass'/>`